# How can I turn Notability into storable value?

Tags: fallen-london

I'm getting ready to take a hiatus from Fallen London: my main stats are in the high 160's, I've finished all of the available content, and much of the dev team's effort is aimed towards Sunless Sea rather than adding more content to Fallen London. I'm not particularly interested in grinding for the small amount of end-game content (5-card housing, Impossible Theorem, the various 3200-Certifiable-Scrap items, etc.). In short, I've gotten bored, but I hope to pick up this game again in a year or two once there's more content.

I could walk away right this very minute, but I have 7 Notability, which will drain away at the rate of one point per week. It was a bit expensive to obtain, so I'd like to get something from it rather than just have it waste away. **Is there a way for me to convert Notability into items or qualities of value, that will remain when I come back in a year or so?**

(I've been seriously considering writing some automation scripts grind for me. This is against Fallen London's Terms of Service, so I've decided the ethical route is just to step away for a while and come back when there's new and interesting content that I will be happy to grind at.)

My character is an Author, and I realize I could spend the Notability to advance to Correspondent (I have Scholar of the Correspondence 10), but I value the Author's weekly reward more than the Correspondent's weekly reward. (And I think the Glassman's reward will be more useful at some point in the future, since I still have uses for Uncanny Incunabulum but not for Antique Mysteries.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [tiny handful of ways](http://fallenlondon.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Notability) to consume Notability for lasting value:

1. Burn 7 Notability to gain Favorable Circumstances, which will let you draw a card of your choice. (This includes the faction cards, the unsigned letter, the presumptuous little opportunity, and others.) You can otherwise get Favorable Circumstances for 8 Fate/Nex, so this is the only option with an equivalent cash value.
2. Upgrade one of your four-card lodgings to a 5-card lodging; this generally requires ~9 Notability, but only burns half of it. This requires some fantastically-expensive items *and* having at least one main stat at 200.
3. Once you've hit the stat cap of 200, Notability can be burned to go over that cap on the Unsigned Letter.
4. Purchasing a Master's Blood with five Tears of the Bazaar requires 7 Notability.

You can also sell it for Prize Tokens in the game of Knife-and-Candle, but those can be stolen by other Knife-and-Candle players; this isn't exactly a store of value.

For my character, then, the only option is to get Favorable Circumstances; I can't afford the Master's Blood.